# Boot Loader not on /C

Tags: bootloader, preinstallation

I installed from Ubuntu live on a second drive (/D), partitioned the boot loader on /D also. I select /D from the boot menu but /C boots up. Do I need the /boot partition on /C? I don't have a lot of space left on /C is why I am trying to place on /d.

Comment: What are /C and /D ? Disks in Linux are typical called /dev/sda, /dev/sdb and so on. An partitoins on /dev/sda are called /dev/sda1, /dev/sda2 ...

Answer (score 0):

You can place Grub, Ubuntu's boot loader, on any drive from which the BIOS can boot.

If Grub was set up correctly you can select any operating system on any drive connected to the computer. If that doesn't work please open a new question with the specific issue.